# Accessing Time Machine backup from Windows/Linux laptops

Tags: backup, time-machine

I'm wondering if I can access my time machine backup from Windows or Linux computers... I'm just wondering what'll happen if my computer fails and I don't have enough money to buy a new mac...

Comment: iiegn has a [python script](http://iiegn.blogspot.com/2009/11/how-to-access-time-machine-files-from.html) that tries to automate the restoring process. I didn't try it yet though.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It CAN be read from linux (By using Ubuntu for example) but it is a tough nut to crack. Windows can't do it at all.

---

The following commands need to be executed as a privileged user. To gain the necessary rights do

```
$ sudo su
```

You should then be prompted with the root shell.

---

The following came from http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20080623213342356

> It turns out Apple does a couple slick
>   things with the file system to make
>   incremental backups work, including
>   hard linking to directories, which
>   isn't allowed in Linux. So for anyone
>   that needs to access their Time
>   Machine from something other than its
>   associated Mac, here's how you do
>   it...
>
> 1 - Mount the drive. On linux, it should automount if you have
>   `gnome-volume-manager` installed. If you
>   don't see it in `/media`, then run
>   nautilus and check the desktop. Still
>   don't see it? Read `man mount`. And then
>   don't forget the `-t hfsplus` flag.
>
> 2 - Change directory. My mount point is /media/Time Machine/. Within that
>   path, I find the directory
>   `Backups.backupdb`. This represents the
>   directory layout of your backup
>   system. Inside that directory is the
>   name of your disk. Inside that are
>   folders labeled with dates
>   corresponding to each incremental
>   backup that was made. Pick the one you
>   want, or choose the Latest symlink.
>   For example, my path is now:

```
/media/Time Machine/Backups.backupdb/Drive 1/2008-06-05-073745
```

> 3 - Find your file's folder. Within that path is a complete representation
>   of your filesystem. Navigate to the
>   location of your file. If it's not too
>   big or nested too deep, it may be
>   plainly visible. However, there's a
>   good chance that its parent directory
>   doesn't exist. Instead you'll see a
>   zero-byte file for the parent that
>   takes its name and acts as a pointer.
>   Run `ls -l` and take note of the first
>   numbered column. Example:

```
...
-r--r--r-- 2155704 root 5791966       0 2007-06-25 02:54 Wallpaper
-r--r--r-- 2155725 root 5791967       0 2007-06-25 02:54 Web-Identity
-r--r--r-- 5441953 root 5791968       0 2007-06-25 02:54 Windows
-r--r--r-- 5511926 root 5791969       0 2007-06-25 02:54 Work
```

> After the permissions, you'll see the
>   directory number that typically refers
>   to the number of directories within
>   that folder. For a file, it should
>   always be 1, but here it is not. What
>   Apple has done is adjust the
>   information in this file's inode to
>   use it as a pointer to the directory
>   that contains the actual file. That
>   way, multiple revisions of the same
>   drive can coexist without duplicating
>   data.
>
> 4 - Find the data. In my case, I want to grab something out of the Wallpaper
>   folder. First I made a note of the
>   directory number, 2155704, and then
>   did `cd /media/Time Machine/.HFS+
>   Private Directory Data` -- this is
>   where the data really lives. From
>   there, I just did `cd dir_2155704`, and
>   voilÃ !

Comment: It is the way to go. you saved my day! I managed to recover some documents from an old time machine backup five years ago. Thanks you so much

Answer (score 7):

I found another script, that creates a read-only FUSE Overlay to implement the TM hardlinking mechanism:

https://github.com/isnotajoke/fuse-time-machine

Answer (score 5):

I've written a script to automate this pain. Find it here: https://gist.github.com/vjt/5183305

Answer (score 4):

Besides the FUSE file system for Time Machine backups [mentioned by strfry and written by Kevan Carstensen](https://github.com/isnotajoke/fuse-time-machine), there exists [an implementation by Ron Pedde](https://github.com/rpedde/tmfuse). In my case the implementation by Carstensen could not properly resolve all links. The one by Pedde worked flawlessly including accessing older versions of the backed up files. Both implementations require you to install [`python-fuse`](https://github.com/libfuse/python-fuse). For Debian-based Linux distributions the following should do:

```bash
sudo apt-get install python-fuse
```

Then assuming your backup disk got automounted to `/media/jonesdoe/backup-disk` you should be able to mount it using `tmfuse.py` like so:

```bash
cd ~jonesdoe
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rpedde/tmfuse/master/tmfuse.py
mkdir mybackup
python tmfuse.py /media/jonesdoe/backup-disk mybackup/
cd mybackup/somehostname/Latest/Macintosh HD
```

As for Windows, [superuser QA: Opening Time-Machine OSX backup files on Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/238297/accessing-time-machine-backup-from-windows-linux-laptops/238303#238303) seems to answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

I recently put together the rpedde/tmfuse solution with torarnv/sparsebundlefs in a docker container with some scripts. It is available here: https://github.com/taborkelly/timemasheen

Comment: Really useful to bundle everything in a docker! I didn't need the sparsebundlefs, so the scripts only worked as an example, but still, this was really useful!

Answer (score 0):

I found that I needed to mount the `.sparsebundle` file found on the network drive first.

On Unix:

1. Follow all the instructions in https://github.com/torarnv/sparsebundlefs the README (read all the subsections, will likely need to follow the steps in the permissions and partition offset sections).
2. Read and follow the steps in the answer by @Pylsa, or use https://github.com/abique/tmfs (again read and follow all instructions).

The complete apt dependencies that I needed to build these 2 repos from source were:

```
sudo apt install libfuse-dev fuse cmake build-essential git curl
```

On Windows:

- Untested, but the above procedure may work with Windows Subsystem for Linux 2 (WSL2).